# RxJava gate mechanism

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-android

I want to implement something like gate mechanism.
I need one PublishSubject and a couple of subscribers. When PublishSubject send data via onNext only **one subscriber** will receive it.

For example:
I have **3 equals fragments** inside tabs. They have **subscription** to global published called **onLoginPublisher**. 
When **onResume** or **onPause** called **gate** becomes open or closed. 
When onLogin called and no gates are opened because of no one of these fragments on screen, onNext will wait for fragment's onResume

Look at the pic:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` with the gate's state. For example, you can wrap all the logic into a class:

```java
public final class GatedSubject<T> {
    final PublishSubject<T> subject = PublishSubject.create();
    final AtomicReferenceArray<Boolean> gates;

    public GatedSubject(int numGates) {
        gates = new AtomicReferenceArray<>(numGates);
    }

    public boolean getGateStatus(int gateIndex) {
        return gates.get(gateIndex) != null;
    }

    public void setGateStatus(int gateIndex, boolean status) {
        gates.set(gateIndex, status ? Boolean.TRUE : null);
    }

    public void Observable<T> getGate(int gateIndex) {
        return subject.filter(v -> getGateStatus(gateIndex));
    }

    public void onNext(T item) {
        subject.onNext(item);
    }

    public void onError(Throwable error) {
        subject.onError(error);
    }

    public void onComplete() {
        subject.onComplete();
    }
}
```

Comment: If every gate are close, onNext data will be lost.

Comment: You need a way to pause a stream, which is currently only available for `Flowable`s via [valve()](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#flowabletransformersvalve).

Comment: Thanks for valve() and your code, this is what I need.